# Is there any modern scalable way to do system call monitoring?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, audit, kernel, kernel-patch-protection

I wrote a kernel module to replace the Linux kernel service routines (e.g. system calls) with security-enforcing code, similar to SELinux or AppArmor, with the main exceptions of ruleset control on-the-fly and big data integration.

From security perspective, The only way to use the OS services from an application is via my supervision code, which is protected by the kernel's native ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) and is read-only.

Since the code and the system calls are marked read-only, they can only be bypassed by another kernel module, which cannot be loaded without approval under most exploit scenarios.

The kernel module communicates MongoDB, sends logs and receives rules on-the-fly.

The result is that every OS service such as disk/file access is logged and can be stopped if a block rule applies.

Is there any way to achieve this result in a scalable and controlled way described above?

`{
 "process": "cat",
 "pid": 14975,
 "accessed file": "/etc/passwd",
 "user id": 1000
}`

Comment: You should ask this question in serverfault SE

Comment: Thank you, i'll copy it. The product inherits GPL license from the kernel so any similar product must be open source too. I thought it's an easy question :-)

Comment: "Is there a product that does X?" is not a good fit here as the answers may change from day to day.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Copy/paste the text and use code formatting. Also, do not cross-post of StackExchange, let the questions get migrated.

Comment: Fixed, please review

Comment: Also, I'm interested in both Security-wise knowledge and serverfault knowledge, is this forbidden and I must delete one of them?

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: I'd like to implement this at customers network, and prefer an existing technology over my own custom code. selinux/apparmor/auditd are not suitable IMHO for enterprise usage.

Comment: @a_at_cyber_dot_training Your module should be an LSM. Don't write your own hooks.